# How to capture and decrypt https traffic in fiddler using python?

Tags: python, ironpython

I need to capture HTTPS traffic in fiddler. Modified registry  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fiddler2\CaptureHTTPS` value to **True** using `ironpython` and tried to capture `HTTPS`.

**But capture failed:**

`!SecureClientPipeDirect failed: System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. on pipe to (CN=***, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com)`

Help me out to capture `HTTPS` in Fiddler using `ironpython` script.